# sending a signal to a background process

Tags: c, linux, signals

Which signal should I send to a background process to move it foreground? SIGTTIN, SIGTOU or...?

Comment: What framework, etc? Much more information needed here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gurudoglu. I think your request's response is here :

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCONT
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTTIN
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTTOU

Comment: good answer - but the question is still fundamentally wrong :)

Comment: None of these signals will move a process into the foreground. SIGCONT will cause a process to resume after it has been SIGSTOP'ped. The SIGTT ones are simply delivered to the process when they attempt to read or write while backgrounded. They do *not* foreground the process, in fact their default action is to simply stop the process as if you had sent a SIGSTOP. You still have to either SIGCONT to have them keep running in the background or fg them from the shell to bring them into the foreground.

Answer (score 20):

It's not signals which directly control whether jobs are foreground or background. The jobs are under the control of a shell (usually).

For example, under `bash`, if you execute:

```
pax> sleep 3600 &
pax> jobs
```

you will see output like:

```
[1]+  Running                 sleep 3600 &
```

Then, you can bring that job back into the foreground by using:

```
pax> fg %1
sleep 3600
```

(and the terminal waits).

Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> *does* send a signal to the process (`SIGSTOP`) as well as putting it into the background but the only signal that can change that is `SIGCONT` (to continue):

```
pax> fg %1
sleep 3600
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 3600
pax> jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 3600
pax> kill -CONT %1
pax> jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 3600 &
```

That will instruct the process to start running again but it *doesn't* bring it into the foreground. For that, you need the `fg` command.

It's probably best to think of signals (which affect the process) and foreground/background (which affect the shell that started the process by determining whether it waits for it, amongst other things) separately.

Comment: you can continue a suspended process send a signal in C like this :

kill(1453, SIGCONT);

I need the name of the signal which can move a background process to foreground like SIGCONT. :)

Comment: There isn't one. Plain and simple. Foreground/background is not an attribute of the process, it's an attribute of the *shell* that started the process. The shell controls that aspect. You can send the SIGCONT to start a process running (if it was stopped with SIGSTOP) but there is no signal that will allow a process to force itself into the foreground because it simply doesn't have that power.

Comment: @gurudoglu - It's like trying to phone up a TV broadcaster and ask them to switch on your TV.  There's no number for that.  Fortunately...

Answer (score 2):

There is no way (In any OS I know of yet) to use a signal to bring a process to the foreground.

I believe you can only bring a process to the foreground using `fg`

Foreground is only relevant in the context of a console, and a signal cannot tell the process what console to foreground to...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Unix and started the process from a shell you could type the following

- Stop Process :: ^Z
- Move process into background :: bg
- Move back into foreground :: fg